# Convert lists present in each column to its respective datatypes

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, data-analysis, data-cleaning

I have a sample dataframe as given below.

```
import pandas as pd

data = {'ID':['A', 'B', 'C', 'D],
    'Age':[[20], [21], [19], [24]],
    'Sex':[['Male'], ['Male'],['Female'], np.nan],
    'Interest': [['Dance','Music'], ['Dance','Sports'], ['Hiking','Surfing'], np.nan]}


df = pd.DataFrame(data)
df
```

[image]
Each of the columns are in list datatype. I want to remove those lists and preserve the datatypes present within the lists for all columns.

The final output should look something shown below.

[image]

Any help is greatly appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: I am not understanding if this question too easy that people are ignoring it or if it is too tough that they are finding it difficult to answer!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Option 1.** You can use the `.str` column accessor to index the lists stored in the DataFrame values (or strings, or any other iterable):

```
# Replace columns containing length-1 lists with the only item in each list
df['Age'] = df['Age'].str[0]
df['Sex'] = df['Sex'].str[0]

# Pass the variable-length list into the join() string method
df['Interest'] = df['Interest'].apply(', '.join)
```

**Option 2.** `explode` Age and Sex, then apply `', '.join` to Interest:

```
df = df.explode(['Age', 'Sex'])
df['Interest'] = df['Interest'].apply(', '.join)
```

Both options return:

```
df

  ID  Age     Sex         Interest
0  A   20    Male     Dance, Music
1  B   21    Male    Dance, Sports
2  C   19  Female  Hiking, Surfing
```

#### EDIT

**Option 3.** If you have many columns which contain lists with possible missing values as `np.nan`, you can get the list-column names and then loop over them as follows:

```
# Get columns which contain at least one python list

list_cols = [c for c in df 
             if df[c].apply(lambda x: isinstance(x, list)).any()]
list_cols

['Age', 'Sex', 'Interest']


# Process each column

for c in list_cols:
    # If all lists in column c contain a single item:
    if (df[c].str.len() == 1).all():
        df[c] = df[c].str[0]
    else:
        df[c] = df[c].apply(', '.join)
```

Comment: What if I have 100 columns? Do I have to assign for each one of then depending upon the data types[float/int/string] present within the list? Is there any more automated way?

Comment: @Shiva I edited my answer to include a third option to automatically process an arbitrary number of columns which contain python lists.

Comment: Almost worked. There is a special case as well. There are some columns containing some NaN values. It it not working for those rows and an error is throwing up. I have edited the dataframe in the question.

Comment: The Nan values be at the first row too. So in your code, df[c] = df[c].str[0] does not hold hood for this.

Comment: @Shiva I see! I've edited my answer again with code that I hope handles missing values in your DataFrame's list columns.